# How to include parameter and event in a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, svelte

I have these components:

Parent.svelte

```
<script>
const myFunction =(event) => {
    console.log(event)
}
</script>
<Child on:doStuff ={myFunction}/>
```

Child.svelte

```
<script>
const doStuff = () ={
    dispatch('testDispatch',{
        'data':'testData'
    }
}
</script>

<button on:click={doStuff}/>
```

The code above works, I can retrieve the dispatched data from the child component.

How do I include another parameter in `myFunction()` in the Parent.svelte so I can get the dispatched event and the parameter since doing the function wrapper makes the event undefined.

Parent.svelte

```
<script>
const myFunction =(???,???) => {
    console.log(event)
}
</script>
<Child on:doStuff ={()=>myFunction(???,???)}/>
```